# Accessing angular 1.x component property from parent

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, model-view-controller, components

I created an angular 1.x star rating component. It is required that there be multiple instances of the component and thus different values for the rating.

However I can't figure out a way to read the starCount variable from the component. I tried going through the docs, trying the binding property but to no avail.

This requires just a v-model attribute in Vue.js but I couldn't find something like this for angular.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.component('star',  {
    template: `<ul class="star">
        <li class="fa" ng-class="$ctrl.starCount >= 1 ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'" ng-click="$ctrl.starCount=1" />
        <li class="fa" ng-class="$ctrl.starCount >= 2 ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'" ng-click="$ctrl.starCount=2" />
        <li class="fa" ng-class="$ctrl.starCount >= 3 ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'" ng-click="$ctrl.starCount=3" />
        <li class="fa" ng-class="$ctrl.starCount >= 4 ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'" ng-click="$ctrl.starCount=4" />
        <li class="fa" ng-class="$ctrl.starCount >= 5 ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'" ng-click="$ctrl.starCount=5" />
    </ul>`,
    controller: function () {
         this.starCount = 0;
    }
});
```

Full Code & Demo Here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBqYoM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a binding to the config to pass data to the component:

```
controller: ...,
bindings: {
    starCount: '<'
}

// in your html
<star star-count="3"></star>
```

Dont forget to remove the `this.starCount = 0;`

Comment: How do I access it from the main app?

Comment: You can use a variable in the controller for your template where you want to use the star component e.g. `$scope.starCount = 5;` and write in the html `<star star-count="starCount"></star>`.

Comment: Could you show a demo ? I tried this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBqYoM but its not working

Comment: It is not updating the values

Comment: I fixed it using two way bindings